# Find the minimum percent increase to make profit after fees

Tags: percentages

I am trading Forex currencies. The platform I use charges a `0.25%` fee for every trade I make.

For this example, let's assume `$2USD` is worth 1 Euro. Also, the fee only affects USD.

Now say I buy `1 Euro` for `2USD`. From that trade, I pay the `0.25%` fee, making my buy actually worth $1.995USD, meaning I receive 0.9975 Euros from the trade.

Now, drastically, the price changes and the exchange rate is now `$3 USD` for `1 Euro`. I decide to profit take, and my `0.9975 Euros` is now worth `$2.9925 USD`. After I pay the fee `($2.9925 - $2.9925 * 0.0025)`, and from that trade, I now have `$2.99 USD`.

What I would like to do is find a formula that will allow me to calculate the minimum percentage of change in the exchange rate needed in order to profit from the trade after the fees. Ideally, I would have a function that would take the buy price (in this case $2) and calculate what percentage of increase I could sell at and still receive a profit after both fees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fee is $x$, after the transaction you have $1-x$ of the amount you invested.  When you make the return transaction you also have $1-x$ of the amount you had before the sale.  The price has to rise $\frac 1{(1-x)^2}$ for you to break even.  If the fee is $0.25\%=0.0025$ you need the price to rise from $1$ to [about $1.0050188$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(1-0.0025)%5E2) to break even.  If the commission is small, the price rise you need is a little greater than two commissions.